# Cursor Index Out Of Bounds Exception - Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm attempting to query my SQLite database but I'm getting the error "Cursor Index Out Of Bounds Exception: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0". When I run the same query in SQLite Man, I get the result I'm looking for.

```
public int getHighScore () {

    String query = "SELECT score FROM " + SCORE_TABLE + ";";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int score = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    return score;

}
```

Comment: Examples http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html and  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if cursor is not null then you want to fetch record from cursor.Use this line to fetch record:
**cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("score")))**

use this code :

```
public int getHighScore () {
int score=0;
    String query = "SELECT score FROM " + SCORE_TABLE + ";";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
   if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     score = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("score")));
}
    cursor.close();
    return score;

}
```

Comment: This solves the "Index Out Of Bounds" exception. I need to figure out why my query is returning a null value now. Thanks.

Comment: Use this query..String query = "SELECT score FROM " + SCORE_TABLE;